# Añadir sonido a notificación

Tags: android, android-notifications

Tengo una notificación que se genera después de un evento, pero quisiera agregarle un sonido por defecto, pero que este mismo sonido no pueda ser cambiado, por aplicaciones de terceros. Alguna idea ?

Mi notificación :

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
                NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
                Intent i=new Intent(ServicioTimer.this, tiempo_carro1.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ServicioTimer.this, 0, i, 0);

                mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(icono)
                        .setContentTitle("Carro 1")
                        .setContentText("Tiempo de carro 1 terminado!")
                        .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

               Random r = new Random(); 
                int randomNo = r.nextInt(100+1);
                mNotifyMgr.notify(randomNo, mBuilder.build());

                mNotifyMgr.notify(randomNo, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Veo que tienes configurado un patrón de vibración, de esa misma forma puedes definir el sonido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Puedes configurar el sonido default** del dispositivo para notificaciones:

```
.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```

**o puedes configurar uno personalizado**, agregando un .mp3 en tu folder `/raw` y usarlo como sonido:

```
.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_sound));
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
                NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
                Intent i=new Intent(ServicioTimer.this, tiempo_carro1.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ServicioTimer.this, 0, i, 0);

                mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(icono)
                        .setContentTitle("Carro 1")
                        .setContentText("Tiempo de carro 1 terminado!")
                        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND); //*Sonido!
                        .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

               Random r = new Random(); 
                int randomNo = r.nextInt(100+1);
                mNotifyMgr.notify(randomNo, mBuilder.build());

                mNotifyMgr.notify(randomNo, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero la pregunta ahora es al añadir el sonido usando una de las dos formas, una aplicación de terceros podría cambiar el sonido por defecto ?

Comment: Si tienes configurado al crear tu notificación reproduzca el sonido default definido en el dispositivo, y si tienes una aplicación que cambia el sonido default es afirmativo. Por eso es recomendable agregar tu propio sonido personalizado y nadie lo puede cambiar  :) !

Comment: comprendo, muchas gracias !