# Definir sonido de notifacion personalizada en mi aplicacion android

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hola estoy entrando mas a fondo en el mundo de android y deseo hacer lo siguiente:
Tengo alertas push que tienen configurado por defecto el sonido predeterminado del S.O.

Como puedo definir un sonido predeterminado en mi aplicación android? Ya tengo el archivo .mp3 en la carpeta `../raw`

NOTA: Vi que se puede configurar al momento de enviar los parámetros de push en firebase pero lamentablemete no tengo acceso a esa parte del código que envía el push y quiero definir el sonido desde android - studio.

**ACTUALIZADO**

Tengo el siguiente código donde se obtiene la ruta del sonido pero está en una clase de firebase que es de solo lectura. Hay alguna manera de modificar o definir el sonido de mi aplicativo de forma predeterminada?

```
   private static Uri getSound(String var0, NotificationParams var1, Resources var2) {
    String var3;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(var3 = var1.getSoundResourceName())) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return !"default".equals(var3) && var2.getIdentifier(var3, "raw", var0) != 0 ? Uri.parse((new StringBuilder(24 + String.valueOf(var0).length() + String.valueOf(var3).length())).append("android.resource://").append(var0).append("/raw/").append(var3).toString()) : RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda agregar el còdigo que realizas para dar respuestas lo mas adecuado tu còdigo , saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias agregué las líneas de código y actualizando mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes tu archivo .mp3 dentro del directorio `/raw`, en el mètodo `.setSound( )` de la notificaciòn define la uri donde se localiza el archivo:

```
val defaultSoundUri: Uri =
                Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_sound)

...
...
...
 .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
```

Es similar como se realiza en Java:

[Añadir sonido a notificación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107866/a%c3%b1adir-sonido-a-notificaci%c3%b3n)

Comment: Tengo un inconveniente esa parte de código está en 'NotificationCompat.java' propio de las librerias de firebase y el archivo es de solo lectura. Hay alguna otra alternativa  para cambiar el sonido de mi app?