# ¿Cómo personalizar el sonido de una notificación en android 8.0?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo este código para las notificaciones de mi APP y funciona bien.

He intentado personalizar el sonido de la notificación, pero no he podido, sigue sonando el sonido por defecto de las notificaciones.

Me podrían decir, por favor, qué tengo mal o qué me falta en el código.

Gracias.

Este es el código del canal y de la notificación.

```java
    Private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "tareas"


    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Notificacion Parametros";
            String description = "Parametros";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }


    private void recordatorio_tareas() {


          NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

          Intent intent = new Intent(recordatorio.this, MainActivity.class);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(recordatorio.this, 0, intent, 0);

          int color = 0x00FF00;

          String mensaje1 = "Recordatorio";
          String mensaje2 = "No olviden trabajar en la manualidad que deben presentar la proxima semana.";

          NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getBaseContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.barney_icono1))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.barney_icono2)
                .setContentTitle(mensaje1)
                .setContentText(mensaje2)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensaje2))
                .setColor(color)
                .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" + getPackageName() +"/" + R.raw.barney_sonido));


            nManager.notify(3, notification.build());

}
```

Comment: Gracias @IvanSanczewski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anteriormente podìas [**cambiar el sonido de la notificaciòn en una aplicaciòn Android**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/107867/95) progràmaticamente sin ningùn problema, pero actualmente debes crear un canal y realizar su configuraciòn que incluye el sonido, al realizar esta configuraciòn en el canal ya no puede ser cambiada.

Lo que se debe realizar para cambiar el sonido de la notificaciòn progràmaticamente es:

**Debemos eliminar el canal de notificación mediante [deleteNotificationChannel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#deleteNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)) y crear uno nuevo con un nuevo id de canal de notificación definiendo la nueva ruta del archivo de sonido.**

```
//Elimina canal de notificaciones
notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(OLD_CHANNEL_ID);

//Crea nueva notificaciòn con nuevo canal y nuevo sonido
      NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getBaseContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.barney_icono1))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.barney_icono2)
            .setContentTitle(mensaje1)
            .setContentText(mensaje2)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensaje2))
            .setColor(color)
            .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" + getPackageName() +"/" + R.raw.barney_sonido));
```

Comment: Hola @Elenasys gracias por tu respuesta. Tengo un problema, cuando coloco la instruccion para borrar el canal anterior, me dice que debo tener API level 26 y yo tengo api minima 16. Pregunta, ¿eso se corrige en el build.gradle(app) minSdkVersion? ¿si lo paso a 26 y elimino el canal, despues me puedo devolver a 16? ¿Existe otra forma de elimar el canal?

Comment: @Isabel, en tu build.gradle que valores tienes inicialmente como compileSdkVersion y targetSdkVersion ?

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, en el build.gradle tengo => compileSdkVersion 30, targetSdkVersion 30 y minSdkVersion 16. Otra cosa que intente fue crear un canal y una notificacion completamente nuevos con un ID diferente, pero no me funciono con el sonido personalizado que quiero, sigue sonando el que trae por defecto. Incluso verifique que el archivo con el sonido estuviera en la carpeta RAW ¿Sera que me falta un permiso?

Comment: @Isabel debes tener el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE definido en tu AndroidManifest.xml y hacer la petición manual del permiso, lo tienes?.

Comment: si señor, tengo el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE definido en AndroidManifest.xml y la petición manual del permiso.

Comment: Revisa en el LogCat si se muestra algún error al tratar de reproducir el sonido.@Isabel

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, estuve revisando mi problema durante varios días y creo que encontre la causa. La propiedad setSound ya no se usa, ahora se debe usar NotificationChannel.SetSound(Uri, AudioAttributes). En este link lo explican https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes)

Comment: Adapte el codigo y me funciona bien, el sonido personalizado que coloque en la carpeta RAW suena perfectamente, pero tengo un inconveniente, cuando voy a mi app en notificaciones en configuracion del telefono (sin modificar nada) y vuelvo a la app ya no suena mi sonido personalizado, lo que suena es el sonido por defecto, Si reinstalo mi app en el telefono queda bien otra vez, pero no puedo ir a configuracion porque vuelve y se daña. ¿que puede ser? @Elenasys

Comment: Hola Isabel, recuerda que puedes realizar una nueva pregunta y hacer referencia a esta, te respondo aquí, lo que sucede es que desde la configuración del dispositivo no puedes realizar modificaciones del canal o sus propiedades, si creaste un canal y quieres modificar sus propiedades debes eliminar el canal mediante código y agregar uno nuevo, son cambios que de hecho afectaron nuestras aplicaciones, al final quitamos el usuario pudiera configurar desde la aplicación el sonido :-(

Comment: Hola @Elenasys que pena, de pronto no me hice entender en mi último comentario. Con este ultimo código, la notificación me funciona bien con el sonido personalizado que le coloque, lo que sucede es que si por alguna razón, voy a configuración/notificaciones de esta APP para ver cómo están configurados los parámetros de la notificación y salgo sin modificar nada y luego vuelvo a mi APP, el sonido personalizado no vuelve a sonar, suena el sonido por defecto, me pasa en api>=26. Ok voy a hacer una nueva pregunta entonces, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Así quedo el código que encontre y adapte, ya no usando la propiedad **setSound** sino **notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes)**;

```
        String mensaje1 = "Recordatorio";
        String mensaje2 = "No olviden trabajar en la manualidad que deben presentar la proxima semana.";

        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" + getPackageName() +"/" + R.raw.barney_sonido);
                    
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CH_ID")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.barney_icono1))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(mensaje1)
                .setContentText(mensaje2)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensaje2))
                .setColor(Color.BLUE)
                .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            if(soundUri != null){
                // Changing Default mode of notification
                notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
                // Creating an Audio Attribute
                AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                        .build();

                // Creating Channel
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("CH_ID","Testing_Audio",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(11, notificationBuilder.build());
```